# realpath() returning false on existing files on Mac OS X XAMPP server

Tags: php, macos, xampp

Basically, I have a script that cannot see an existing directory on the OS X machine. The directory has been copied off an external hard drive onto the desktop, which I think may be the core of the issue.

```
    $path = '/Users/username/Desktop/testfolder';
    $path = realpath($path);
```

This above doesn't work.

```
    $path = '/Users/username/Desktop';
    $path = realpath($path);
```

This above works fine.

I'll give you a little context of the situation. I'm running Mac OS X Lion 10.7. I have installed XAMPP. This is a kiosk iMac that needs to communicate with an iPad on the same network, otherwise I wouldn't be running apache on OS X. The iPad needs to retrieve some images off of the iMac, and the PHP is basically functioning as a proxy to do this. I've created a backend that lets the administrator setup the path to the images, which is where this error is occuring.

So, I'm not sure what is going on. I imagine it has to do with some conflict of permissions and owner of these files from the external hard drive. I am sure we could do a "chown" or "chmod" in Terminal, but this isn't really a great solution. I love to make the PHP accommodate such a scenario. Any thoughts? Please!? :-)

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) does state `The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE.` - if this is not true (as I suspect it isn't, it sounds like you don't have execute permissions on `testfolder`) then the *only* solution is `chmod`/`chown`/`chgrp`. It may not be a great solution, but you'll just have to learn to like it...

Comment: Since the ladder path works, it obviously has permissions up to Desktop, just not on testfolder. So, knowing this, I tried creating a second directory locally on the machine called "testfolder2" and copied the images from testfolder into testfolder2, yet I received the same issue. realpath was returning false on the new folder. Any thoughts?

Comment: If the PHP script doesn't have exec on `testfolder` or `testfolder2`, it won't work. Try `chmod 777`ing the folders and see if you still have a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a weird issue, but although this works:

```
$path = '/Users/username/Desktop';
$path = realpath($path);
```

The "Desktop" directory didn't have correct permissions. Once I changed permissions on Desktop, it allowed me to access this path:

```
$path = '/Users/username/Desktop/testfolder';
$path = realpath($path);
```

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) does state `The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE.` which did seem to be the issue.